# Why does my windows 7 go to sleep after two minutes regardless of power management settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows, sleep, power-management

My computer goes to sleep two minutes after being idle. I have checked power management options for unplugged and plugged settings and going to sleep, screen saver etc. are all put on never but it still goes to sleep. Although a corporate pc the computer is not managed remotely by any admin and does not have any remote changes being applied to it and I have got a confirmation of this today as well.

Are there any other settings that i need to check/change?

Comment: A similar case I came across was due to third party power management software. PS. Although I never came across this case, I could imagine BIOS settings might be responsible too, but that's just a wild guess

Comment: You sure it's going to sleep and not just turning off the LCD backlight?  Check your BIOS settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this before- it was also a corporate PC (i.e. on a domain) that I saw with this behaviour. In my case I had to log in using the LOCAL administrator account and disable the power saving options in there. For some reason the local admin account was overriding even the domain administrator account.

It's only happened to me once- but made me realize that this isn't always as simple as setting the desired power savings settings under ANY administrative account and expecting it to override everything else.