# Windows 10 sleeps with all settings disabling it

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I've set all settings to "off" for my Windows 10 laptop to go to sleep, but after a few minutes of no usage, it sleeps (even less than the minimum 5 min timeout).

What can I do to debug this? Are there specific logs I can look into?

EDIT:

Running `powercfg /a` gives:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S3)
    Hibernate
    Hybrid Sleep
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
```

Also: in the Control Panel, "Put the computer to sleep" is set to "Never".

Comment: Is your pc overheating, maybe? That is a reason for the pc to go into sleep.

Comment: @LPChip no, it's very cool and it has external fans too

Comment: Please open an administrator command prompt and copy and paste the result of powercfg /a

Comment: bfuona - See solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time/1255165#1255165

Comment: @bfuona That's the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

We can try the following setting:
Firstly, open the registry, locate to
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0", modify the value data of "Attributes".
The default value data is 1, we set it 2.

[image]

Secondly, in sleep option, we can see "System unattended sleep timeout" option. Open control panel->All control panel Items->Power Options->Edit plane settings: sleep\System unattended sleep timeout\setting:**0 minutes**
[image]

Then we can see if the laptop will go to sleep.