# Windows Task automatically wakes my computer, but doesn't put it back to sleep after

Tags: windows, sleep, windows-task-scheduler, wake-up, windows-10-v1903

My computer wakes itself up every day (presumably to do updates) which is fine by me, but it heats up my room by a considerable amount, and I rather not shut down, especially because it will automatically update in sleep mode. My only issue is that it doesn't put itself back to sleep once it is done doing whatever it is doing. Is there a way to force it to go back to sleep once it is done?

output of powercfg -lastwake:

```
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 1
Wake Source [0]
Type: Wake Timer
Owner: [SERVICE] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\System32\svchost.exe (SystemEventsBroker)
Owner Supplied Reason: Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Universal Orchestrator Start' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.
```

Comment: What is your sleep timer set to in power settings? “Sleep after x minutes of inactivity?”

Comment: @Appleoddity 5 hours, but that is what I want it to be during the day. At night I want it to sleep when it can.

Comment: Mine would appear to sleep as expected for a couple of days before the unexpected wake; in my case I assume it was because of the update schedule checking perhaps weekly rather than daily. But I had the same issue - as if update disables the inactivity timeouts while it runs but forgets to re-enable them when done. My work-around was to disable all wake timers in advanced power settings.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is by default configured to timeout and return to sleep two minutes
after a system unattended wake up.

To verify these settings, start `regedit` and navigate to the key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`.

You will see here three entries:

```
381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e    Balanced
8c5e7fda-e8bf-4a96-9a85-a6e23a8c635c    High performance
a1841308-3541-4fab-bc81-f71556f20b4a    Power saver
```

Click on the entry corresponding to your power plan and verify the settings
for the items
`ACSettingIndex` for when plugged in and `DCSettingIndex` for when on battery.

Both items should have by default the value of "0x00000078 (120)".
If they don't show this value, then set them as above.

For more information and methods, see the articles:

- [How to Change System Unattended Sleep Timeout in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87782-change-system-unattended-sleep-timeout-windows-10-a.html)
- [Windows 7: Sleep Return Timeout for Unattended Wake Up](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/35767-sleep-return-timeout-unattended-wake-up.html)

Comment: Yes, both are still set to this value but it does not go to sleep after 2 minutes, it just remains on until I put it back to sleep.

Comment: Strange - looks like something is wrong. Please also check the [System unattended sleep timeout setting](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87782-change-system-unattended-sleep-timeout-windows-10-a.html#option1), which may require to [add "System unattended sleep timeout" to Power Options](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/72133-add-system-unattended-sleep-timeout-power-options-windows.html).

Comment: I have the same problem and registry shows correct timeouts just like for OP.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is caused by customized power plan settings. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1254772/8672) on how to restore the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by selecting the "Balanced" power plan in Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Power Options. My theory, after reading harrymc's reply, is that the custom power plan I had created, didn't have an entry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\238C9FA8-0AAD-41ED-83F4-97BE242C8F20\7bc4a2f9-d8fc-4469-b07b-33eb785aaca0\DefaultPowerSchemeValues`.
If that doesn't work, try clicking "change plan settings" and "restore default settings for this plan". Then of course make sure this plan is selected.