# Windows 10 Update and sleep

Tags: windows, windows-update, sleep

I have a new Windows 10 Pro laptop recently upgraded to version 1903. I have moved away from the default settings for sleep and Windows Update because of various issues.

I disabled connected standby mode because it would not sleep/was too easily woken.

I have also disabled automatic updates (via group policy) because it had the annoying tendency to disrupt my work with its automatically scheduled installs and restarts.

Believing the computer would remain asleep until I commanded it to wake, I was surprised to find one morning that the screen was on and likely had been so most of the night. Checking the event log, it appeared that the system was awakened to install an update but never went back to sleep. To remedy this, I have also disabled all wake timers. Now, I will get notifications of pending updates, but have to do command the installations/restarts myself. Had the computer gone back to sleep after completing its update, I would never have noticed and I don't think I'd mind. FWIW I have it configured to turn off the screen after 10 minutes of inactivity and go to sleep after one hour of inactivity, and the update appears to have successfully completed several hours before I noticed the computer with the screen on - well beyond both the screen off and sleep timeout settings.

My question is: Is it a known issue for Windows to fail to go sleep after installing updates? Is there a combination of settings that would reliably allow the computer automatically wake, update, and go back to sleep (not involving connected standby)?

Comment: "Is it a known issue for Windows to fail to go sleep after installing updates" - No

Comment: Duplicate but can't be flagged as such since no answer is upvoted/accepted : https://superuser.com/questions/1454626/windows-task-automatically-wakes-my-computer-but-doesnt-put-it-back-to-sleep-a/1462013

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Task automatically wakes my computer, but doesn't put it back to sleep after](https://superuser.com/questions/1454626/windows-task-automatically-wakes-my-computer-but-doesnt-put-it-back-to-sleep-a)

Comment: @Ramhound I'd accept the question you referenced as "close enough" to consider mine a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try running powercfg /requests to see which programs are preventing it from going to sleep. Make sure to run as admin, and then remove those processes.

If this doesn't work, try disabling fast boot.