# Why does my computer lock up whenever I'm away 1 minute?

Tags: windows-10, office365, lock-screen, azure-activedirectory, face-recognition

I have used laptops with Windows 10 for years, and only now that I'm starting to use a higher line of laptop, still with Windows 10, am I having trouble with it locking up as often as I walk away for 1 minute. I have confirmed that my computer is set to never go to sleep nor turn off the screen, whatever power it is running on. Screen saver is also set to "(None)".

The machine itself is not my first but my fourth guess of the problem. Some other new things about the system are that:

1. I have a managed account that exists on AzureAD; until I created a local account, Windows ignored the fact that I had admin rights, which seems a similar problem
2. I set up facial recognition login, which is how I'm logging back in every time I return
3. I'm renting Microsoft 365 instead of using a bought version of Office

If I can confirm that one of these is indeed the cause of my problem, I have high hopes of convincing the owners to change the protocol.

Comment: Take a look at the top answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1019043/windows-10-sleeps-before-set-time

Answer (score 0):

I think the facial recognition setup may be what's causing this behavior since it could be a security feature, because when you get away from your computer for a short amount of time there is a high risk that someone else can use your device however they like, especially that your account has admin privileges.

My answer is from a security standpoint, feel free to correct my understanding of your situation.

Comment: There is a group policy to set the timeout period

Comment: Then @Post169 should try tweaking it and tell us what he got.

Answer (score 0):

Select **Settings** right click **Windows icon**:
[image]
Select **Personalization**- **Lock screen**- **Screen saver settings**:
[image]
Select **(None)** for Screen Saver- and uncheck the option: On resume, display logon screen.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I have already confirmed that screen saver is set to (None). I have a different problem.